# SQL - Why is parameter trimmed

Tags: sql, trim

I have a table (t) with a column (c) defined as varchar 20, containing the values 'a', 'b' and 'c'

If I execute the following sql, a value is returned:

```
select * from table where c = 'a    '
```

Why?

I assume it's casting/trimming the parameter in some way, but why?

How would I really search for `'a    '`

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To compare it to a varchar column, your string literal must also be a varchar type.  Varchar does trim extra ending white space.  It *varies*, hence VARchar.  The plain the char type does not trim the whitespace, and will actually append extra spaces on the end of a literal if need be.  You can check for this (and fix your search with the LEN() function:

```
 declare @a varchar(20) = 'a     '
 select * from t where c = @a and len(@a) = Len(c)
```

Comment: I found that using len didn't solve this - if I did:
declare @a varchar(20)
set @a = 'a   '
select len(c), len(@a), * from t where c = @a and len(c) = len(@a)
it returned a row, and the len values were both 4

If I used datalength however, it didn't succeed.

Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Trailing space is specified to be handled in a special way in the ANSI SQL Standard:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/316626

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154886/EN-US/

This behavior is effectively the same for both char and varchar.

Answer (score 0):

I used simple solution:

```
declare @a varchar(20) = 'a     '
select * from t where c + '$' = @a  + '$'
```